# If $r$ is a nonzero solution $ x^2 + ax + b$, prove that $r | b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I know that if $r$ is a solution, then there exist two factors of $b$ that when multiplied equal $b$ and that $r$ is one of them. So clearly $r$ divides $b$, but I don't know if there is any other way to formally prove it?

Comment: Well, firstly what you have there is an expression, not an equation. And secondly, where do your symbols live? Are they all supposed to be integers, since you're discussing divisibility?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $a$, $b$ and $r$ are integers, it is true. $r$ is a nonzero solution of $x^2 + ax + b$, that is, $r^2 + ar + b = 0$ or $b = -r(r+a)$.

But if either of $b$ or $r$ are not integers, "$r|b$" is nonsense, and if $a$ is not an integer it may or may not be true. For example, $x^2 + 2.5x + 1$ has a solution $r=-2$, and $-2$ does not divide $b=1$.

Comment: Very well stated!

Comment: $r \mathrel{|} b$ is *not* nonsense if $b$ and $r$ are not integers, but it does depend on what ring you are working in (hence Chappers' comment on the original question).

Comment: Yeah. I'm assuming that we're in the reals and divisibility is only defined for the integers.